# ImportError: No module named django.utils

Tags: django, django-views, integration-testing, django-testing

I have an integrationTest case written in django webFrameWork using Tastypie.

test_file.py

```
  from django.utils import unittest

  @unittest.skip('skipping')
  def test_admission(self):
  self.check_entity('admission',admission,'Not validate ')
```

Command to run integration Test Case on terminal:

```
(/home/arya/trunk/integrationtests) arya-$ nosetests  -v  test_file.py
```

On importing django.utils to skip this integrationTest case, Following error is throwing on terminal :

**ERROR OUPUT :**

```
Failure: ImportError (No module named django.utils) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named django.utils)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/arya/trunk/integrationtests/test_file.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils import unittest
ImportError: No module named django.utils

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Is there any fault in settings or some other reason?

Comment: No, I have my own API made using tastypie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
import unittest
```

instead of

```
from django.utils import unittest
```

Comment: Yeah ,its working , but how do you know , unittest has to import directly?